# How to css html to display image in IE, which can be viewed in firefox, chrome, and safari?

Tags: html, css, image, internet-explorer

These images on the bottom left of this link http://giantmango.com/i-love-art-13-3319 display in firefox, chrome, safari, but not in IE.

How do I get them to show in IE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HTML for your images currently looks like this:

```
<img src="....." alt="" title="I Love Art" width="200"   width="200" height=""/>
```

The problem is the empty `height` attribute (IE is treating this as though the `height` is set to `1`). Remove the attribute entirely.

You should also remove the duplicated `width` attribute, so the final HTML is similar to:

```
<img src="....." alt="" title="I Love Art" width="200" />
```

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, in IE, the `img` element has the `height` attribute set to **1**.

```
<img width="200" height="1" title="I Love Art" alt="" src="http://giantmango.com/wp-content/uploads/japanese-style.jpg" complete="complete"/>
```